# Numpy/Python split an array by precentage by using jumps

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy list

```
input_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...]
```

I am looking for a way to split it by percentage value in this manner:
So for 50% split it will split the array equally between both lists.

```
out1,out2 = splitArrayby(input_list,0.5)
>> [0,2,4,6,...] , [1,3,5,7,...]
```

For 66% it will take first item to first list, and then two items to second list.

```
out1,out2 = splitArrayby(input_list,0.66)
>> [0,3,6,...] , [1,2,4,5,7,8,..]
```

The jumps are most important than maintaining an accurate ratio. So it is ok if last items in the input array are not split evenly

Probably can be done with a for loop. Is there a more "Pythonic" way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure python, without `numpy`, You could use the [filter](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter) operator on the following **anonymous** function.

```py
l = list(filter(lambda x : input_list.index(x)%2==0, input_list))
# includes [0, 2, 4, 6]
l = list(filter(lambda x : input_list.index(x)%2==1, input_list))
# includes [1, 3, 5]
```

Here, you test whether the index of the element is odd or event

For 0.66, you would just use `%2==0` VS `%2==1` or `%2==2`

```py
 l = list(filter(lambda x : input_list.index(x)%3==1 or input_list.index(x)%3==2, input_list))
```

Comment: I found a solution using numpy, but I like yours better

Comment: functional programming in modern python is just amazing!!

Comment: This works nicely for 'simple' ratios but quickly becomes problematic when the ratio is set to something like `.472`.

Comment: Indeed. I did not have any insight on this complexity

Answer (score 1):

I made solution using numpy before zar3bski solution:

```
import math

def splitArrayBy(idx,pattern):
  fullmask = ([0]*pattern[0]+[1]*pattern[1])*math.ceil(len(idx)/sum(pattern))
  fullmask = np.array(fullmask[:len(idx)])
  if isinstance(idx,(np.ndarray))==False:
    idx = np.array(idx)
  out0 = idx[np.where(fullmask==0)]
  out1 = idx[np.where(fullmask==1)]
  return out0,out1
```

examples how it works:

```
idx=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
out0,out1 = splitArrayBy(idx,[1,1])
>> (array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10]), array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11]))
out0,out1 = splitArrayBy(idx,[2,1])
>>(array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  6,  7,  9, 10]), array([ 2,  5,  8, 11]))
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches is to first determine the ratio of the desired split. Then we can use the numerator to loop over the list and the denominator as the step size. That yields part a. Part b is simply the counterpart of that result.

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

a_list = list(range(42))
split = .7
split_ratio = Decimal(str(split)).as_integer_ratio()

part_a = []
counter = 0
for i in range(0, split_ratio[0]):
    part_a.extend(a_list[i::split_ratio[1]])
part_a.sort()
part_b = np.setdiff1d(a_list, part_a).tolist()
```

Example output:

```
>>> part_a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 40, 41]
>>> part_b
[7, 8, 9, 17, 18, 19, 27, 28, 29, 37, 38, 39]
```